# Scaffolding not working when inherit IdentityUser and IdentityDbContext - Wep Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an api, initially when scaffolding I did it without any problem. But once my entity User inherit from IdentityUser and database context inherit from IdentityDbContext  the errors started the scaffolding does not work and it gives me the following error.
**Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IndexBuilder Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.HasIndex (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1 <System.Func`2 <System .__ Canon, System. Object >>) '.**

I am working with Visual 2019 and asp.net core 3.1 the additional layers Core and Infrastructure with NetStandar 2.0

In the Core I have my entities and in Infrastructure the context of the database.
The first image corresponds to the Api project, the second to Core and the last to Infrastructure.
If someone can tell me what the mistake is, I will be very grateful.
Greetings!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the code instead of images of it.

Comment: I resolved my problem, I changed NetStandar 2.0 to  NetStandar 2.1.